# Regex pattern to match a url string for just the latin woff2 file in a Google Fonts stylesheet

Tags: regex

I'd like to preload a specific subset of woff2 files from Google Fonts.
For a given Google Font url
e.g.
[https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:regular,500italic,600,300italic,700|Dosis:regular,800&display=optional](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:regular,500italic,600,300italic,700%7CDosis:regular,800&display=optional)

Google will return woff2 files for multiple subsets - which I do eventually need (so no - the subset param won't help me with this question!).

I'm downloading the woff2 files (which is fine and implemented) but my Regex skills are basic and I'm struggling with coming up with a pattern to parse the following output to match the urls in the latin blocks.

Each @font-face woff2 url that I need has the `/* latin */` above it, so ideally something that finds these and then matches the `src:url` line would be ideal.

Any ideas?

```
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v18/HhyaU5sn9vOmLzlnC_WoEoZKdbA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v18/HhyaU5sn9vOmLzlmC_WoEoZKdbA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v18/HhyaU5sn9vOmLzloC_WoEoZK.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v18/HhyaU5sn9vOmLzlnC_WoEoZKdbA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v18/HhyaU5sn9vOmLzlmC_WoEoZKdbA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v18/HhyaU5sn9vOmLzloC_WoEoZK.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTmvIRce_fuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTmvIRccvfuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTmvIRcdffuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTmvIRceffuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTmvIRcePfuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTmvIRcdvfuJGl18Q.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTm5IVce_fuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTm5IVccvfuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTm5IVcdffuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTm5IVceffuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTm5IVcePfuJGl18QRY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX7KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdTm5IVcdvfuJGl18Q.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdzeFaxOedfTDw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdXeFaxOedfTDw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdLeFaxOedfTDw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhd7eFaxOedfTDw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhd_eFaxOedfTDw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKhdHeFaxOedc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjQ76AIxsdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjQ76AIVsdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjQ76AIJsdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjQ76AI5sdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjQ76AI9sdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjQ76AIFsdP3pBms.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjWr7AIxsdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjWr7AIVsdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjWr7AIJsdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjWr7AI5sdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjWr7AI9sdP3pBmtF8A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: optional;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ibmplexsans/v8/zYX9KVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKjWr7AIFsdP3pBms.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
\/\* latin \*\/(?:[\r\n]+[^\r\n]+){6}src: url\((.+woff2)\)\s
```

See regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/OOryzh/2).

Regex Explanation:

```
\/\* latin \*\                 //Match /* latin */
/(?:[\r\n]+[^\r\n]+){6}        //Match 6 lines down (last is the src line)
src: url                       //Match the src: url line
\((.+woff2)\)\s                //Match URL and extract as Group 1.
```